# How to use CopyWebpackPlugin to copy static assets

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5, copy-webpack-plugin

I'm using this configuration pattern:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin({
    patterns: [{
        from: `src/assets/static/**/*`,
        to: 'dist',
    }]
})
```

But this results to

- from -> src/assets/static/images
- to-> dist/src/assets/static/images

Expected Output:

- from -> src/assets/static/images
- to-> dist/assets/static/images

Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```js
new CopyWebpackPlugin({
    patterns: [{
        context: './src/assets/static/images',
        from: './**/*',
        to: './assets/static/images',
    }]
});
```

Eventually you can try with `to: './dist/assets/static/images'`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you adjust the **to** configuration slightly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).